# Why are the values being made into "None" instead of "LIVE"?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is Game of Life program. When I tested it, my surrounding(row,col) function returned 0 even if the configuration file indicated that 8 squares would be made "LIVE." Just ran a test by printing the board after opening the configuration file, and it turns out instead of making the indicated squares say 'LIVE,' the ones that are 'LIVE' say 'None' so no 'LIVE' values are being counted.

[[None, None, None, 0, 0, 0, 0], [None, 0, None, 0, 0, 0, 0], [None, None, None, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]] is what I get when I `print board`. Can't see what I'm missing here?

```
LIVE = 1
DEAD = 0

def board(canvas, width, height, n):
    for row in range(n+1):
        for col in range(n+1):
            canvas.create_rectangle(row*height/n,col*width/n,(row+1)*height/n,(col+1)*width/n,width=1,fill='black',outline='green')                      

n = int(raw_input("Enter the dimensions of the board: "))
width = n*25
height = n*25

from Tkinter import *
import math

window=Tk()
window.title('Game of Life')

canvas=Canvas(window,width=width,height=height,highlightthickness=0)
canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=5)

board = [[DEAD for row in range(n)] for col in range(n)]

rect = [[None for row in range(n)] for col in range(n)]


for row in range(n):
    for col in range(n):      
        rect[row][col] = canvas.create_rectangle(row*height/n,col*width/n,(row+1)*height/n,(col+1)*width/n,width=1,fill='black',outline='green') 

#canvas.itemconfigure(rect[2][3], fill='red') #rect[2][3] is rectangle ID

#print rect

f = open('filename','r') #filename is whatever configuration file is chosen that gives the step() function to work off of for the first time
for line in f:
    parsed = line.split()
    print parsed
    if len(parsed)>1:
        row = int(parsed[0].strip())
        col = int(parsed[1].strip())
        board[row][col] = LIVE
        board[row][col] = canvas.itemconfigure(rlist[row][col], fill='red')        

def surrounding(row,col):
    count = 0
    if board[(row-1) % n][(col-1) % n] == LIVE:
        count += 1
    if board[(row-1) % n][col % n] == LIVE:
        count += 1
    if board[(row-1) % n][(col+1) % n] == LIVE:
        count += 1
    if board[row % n][(col-1) % n] == LIVE:
        count += 1
    if board[row % n][(col+1) % n] == LIVE:
        count += 1
    if board[(row+1) % n][(col-1) % n] == LIVE:
        count +=1
    if board[(row+1) % n ][col % n] == LIVE:
        count += 1
    if board[(row+1) % n][(col+1) % n] == LIVE:
        count += 1
    print count
    return count

surrounding(1,1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're assigning to the items of your `board` nested list twice:

```
    board[row][col] = LIVE
    board[row][col] = canvas.itemconfigure(rlist[row][col], fill='red')
```

The first assigns `1` to the appropriate value, the second replaces the `1` with `None`, since that's the return value of `canvas.itemconfigure` when called with those arguments. I suspect (without testing it) that you should simply remove the assignment from the second statement:

```
    board[row][col] = LIVE
    canvas.itemconfigure(rlist[row][col], fill='red')
```

This might still have issues (such as `rlist` needing to be `rect`, perhaps?), but the issue with `None` values should be resolved.